# Printing results common to many grep

Tags: bash, grep

How can I use two grep statements and print only those files which satisfy both the grep searches....
OR
How can I look for two different String in a file and print the contents of the file if it contain both the Strings ?

Comment: Please post samples of inputs and expected outputs in code tags in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```
pattern1=your-pattern
pattern2=your-pattern
basedir=/path/to/dir
grep -Zlr "$pattern1" "$basedir" | xargs -0 grep -l "$pattern2"
```

The key elements:

- The `-l` flag is to print the names of files that matched.
- The `-Z` flag is to output a null-byte after matched filenames
- `xargs -0` will expect null terminated items in its input
- The first `grep` will find files matching `pattern1`, the second grep will find files matching `pattern2` -> the end result is a list of files matching both patterns.

Comment: Is  this Correct ?
grep -r -C5 -i -h "${var[1]}" "$basedir" | xargs -0 grep "${var[2]}"

Comment: I have a file :
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Now if my var[1] = line 2 and var[2]=line 3
Will this give the expected output?

Comment: @AniketGupta not correct. The `-C` is pointless there, and you missed the `-Z` and `-l` flags despite my explanation that they are essential. Try this: `grep -Zlri "${var[1]}" "$basedir" | xargs -0 grep -l "${var[2]}"`

Comment: can you please tell me how can I use grep to print whole file instead of just the matching line

Comment: @AniketGupta print the full content of all the files that match both patterns? -> `grep -Zlri "${var[1]}" "$basedir" | xargs -0 grep -Zl "${var[2]}" | xargs -0 cat`

Comment: This prints multiple matching results continuously , How can I distinguish them ?

Comment: @AniketGupta `grep -Zlr C . | xargs -0 grep -Zl C | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'echo {}; cat "{}"'`